# SDL memory leak

Tags: c, rendering, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

So I tryed to make something on SDL, but on first programm I have memory lear (idk leak or not) so there is some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#define SCREENSIZEX 180
#define SCREENSIZEY 300
SDL_Window* mainwind = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* rend = NULL;
TTF_Font* Usefont = NULL;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    Uint32 windowflags;
    windowflags = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN;
    mainwind = SDL_CreateWindow("FooBar", 
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
                                SCREENSIZEX, 
                                SCREENSIZEY, 
                                windowflags);
    rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(mainwind, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    IMG_Init(imgFlags);
    TTF_Init();
    Usefont = TTF_OpenFont("DOTMBold.TTF",90);

    SDL_Surface* TextSurf = NULL;
    SDL_Texture* TextTexture = NULL;

    SDL_Color UsingColor;
    UsingColor.r=0;
    UsingColor.g=255;
    UsingColor.b=255;
    UsingColor.a=100;

    bool exit = false;
    char Text[500];
    int counter = 0;
    SDL_Event evneet;
    while(!exit)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&evneet);
        SDL_RenderClear(rend);
        counter++;
        TextSurf = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(Usefont, Text, UsingColor);
        TextTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(rend, TextSurf);
        SDL_FreeSurface(TextSurf);
        TextSurf = NULL;
        SDL_RenderCopy(rend, TextTexture, NULL, NULL);
        TextTexture = NULL;
        SDL_DestroyTexture(TextTexture);
        SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(TextSurf);
    TextSurf = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyTexture(TextTexture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(mainwind);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;   
}
```

Problem:
[some screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kpEZ.png)

Idk how to fix this and tryed to do a lot of freeing and memory manipulations.
This programm do only one task. Just counting frames (in code only 0 displayed)
Its 3rd my try to make rendering and always i got the same.
Please help!

Comment: Your chart doesn't necessarily show a memory leak; what exactly does it measure?

Comment: Why do you set `TextTexture` to `NULL` before call to `SDL_DestroyTexture` ?

Comment: Why do you create textures every frame?.. that will destroy performance.

Comment: Is that your actual code, or errors are introduced by bad copy-paste (in that case, quesion will make no sense)? If it is, then it is rather strange why in addition to resetting texture pointer before destroying it (which seems like the source of your resource leak problems), you also have uninitialised `Text` array and unclear means of breaking your main loop - not shown in question, but `SDL_PollEvent` return value should not be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was strange. Thanks Ctx thats first part of this big mess with rerenderring surfaces and textuers. As for me big mistake was NULLing texture when i need to pass "nullptr".

```
SDL_FreeSurface(AlreadyDrawedAndUsedOnSurface);
AlreadyDrawedAndUsedOnSurface = NULL;    //BAD!
AlreadyDrawedAndUsedOnSurface = nullptr; //good)
```

Very strange for me but it works!

Answer (score 6):

This looks suspicious:

```
while(!exit)
{
    ...
    TextTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(rend, TextSurf);
    ...
    TextTexture = NULL;                // A
    SDL_DestroyTexture(TextTexture);   // B
    ...
}
```

`SDL_DestroyTexture()` doesn't get a valid handle here, but a `NULL`-Pointer is passed. You have to swap the lines A and B, so the Texture can be freed properly.

Comment: Not in the texture problem

Comment: And more. I wrote an fps meter on surfaces. without rendering all the stuff. And it still there